# jQuery slideToggle just shows and hides but doesn't animate correctly

Tags: jquery, animation, html, slidetoggle

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/7xzMa/1/) my div container just hides and shows but doesn't do the [awesome jQuery animation](http://jsfiddle.net/tdsUC/).

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('.class1').slideToggle();
});
```

Can anybody say me why? I know that animations on tables don't work correctly but on divs it should be okay.

UPDATE
Thanks for all the answers. The information I was missing is that position absolute removes the element from the DOM. And yeah I know I should put the style in a css--this version was just for quick testing, but thanks for the answers!!!

Comment: Out of interest, did you have jQuery and jQuery UI on the page, I'v found slideup/down doesn't work if jQuery UI is also included.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.slideToggle() animates the height of an element from 0% - 100%, hiding its children as it goes.

By using position:absolute throughout your fiddle, you are removing the child elements from the flow of the DOM and interfering with the ability of the parent element to incrementally hide its children.

If you set overflow to hidden, and remove position:absolute from the children, this works properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/7xzMa/6/

Comment: Hmm thats not good cause i need this layout >.< That means i need to figure out how i can keep the style without position absolute and it workt right? I just used position absolute cause im bad with css. okay i just put another div around the left informations and used float:left and it works. thankns for the quick reply

Comment: This worked well in my case I had to set the width to 100% as I wanted a full width panel to drop down then I simply used $('.toggleButton').on("click", function () { $('#myHiddenDiv').slideToggle(700);  });

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED YOUR FIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/7xzMa/14/ --- cleaned the divs and you should place css into a style sheet so its easier to edit. "display" should be set to "none". unless you would like it to be visible then click to hide. http://jsfiddle.net/7xzMa/8/

Comment: added easing functions to open it smoother goodluck <br />http://jsfiddle.net/7xzMa/9/

Comment: You have written all the css, just add a clas="divname" that references to you css sheet .divname { then add all your styles} updated css for you what is the problem with you position?  http://jsfiddle.net/7xzMa/14/

Comment: You need to build your div better. if your container div is 100px and you want 2 divs in it do not use position absolute tell 1 div to be width:40px float:left. and the next div to be width:60px; float:right; if you add padding make sure you minus that off the total width.

Answer (score 1):

Artur, my recommendation is to restructure your code entirely, there is way too much going on.  Short and simple is always best. I'd start by getting rid of the "style" attributes in your html. Make sure to put styles in CSS (it's cleaner and easier to maintain -- much better than deleting styles from multiple tags).
I just made you a demo, hope it helps! Feel free to use it! Happy coding! http://jsfiddle.net/7xzMa/17/

Answer (score 1):

use JQuery UI

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        $('.class1').toggle('slide',{direction: 'up'},500);
    });
});
```